# Scanline Flood Fill Algorithm for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, flood-fill

I try to use https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill ,but when image have another resolution than 640x640 , flood fill work bad, it filling wrong area with some shift which dependent from resolution big or small from 640x640.

When I delete multiplication touch points code:
"
    tpoint.x = tpoint.x * 2 ;
    tpoint.y = tpoint.y * 2 ;
"
 from template in "FloodFillImageView" class. It's start work for iPad, but again only for 640x640.

Can somebody explain what I missed and why this code work not for all resolution and have problem with fill for different devices.
And of course Im glad to see maybe some code to solve my issue or what I must changed in this code, or some explanation how to make it work.

Comment: Have you got any workaround for this? I am also facing the same issue in this.

Comment: Hi can you give me size of your imageview and image?

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked out the imageView size and the image resolution, image size is 320X320 and the image itself(star.png) is 640 X 640 that is why tpoint.x = tpoint.x * 2 ; and tpoint.y = tpoint.y * 2 ; multiplied by two. tpoint is the coordinates that you have touched. and you have to calculate where the point you touched comes on the image.